# Does every element have a critical mass?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, elements

We have all heard of critical mass for radioactive materials like Uranium, Plutonium etc. but does every element theoretically have a critical mass?  If not, what determines if such a phenomena is possible or not for a specific element?

Comment: FYI: "Mass" has more than one meaning. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mass The "mass" in "critical mass" does not refer to any definite amount of substance. In fact, "critical mass" is a bit of a misnomer. A better name would be, "critical _configuration._" The amount of uranium that you'd need to achieve criticality depends on the _geometry_ of the mass and, on the geometry of masses of other substances (esp. neutron reflectors, neutron absorbers, and neutron moderators) that are in close proximity to the uranium.

Comment: P.S., Read about how [_nuclear chain reactions_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_chain_reaction) work. Not all nuclides will split apart and emit more neutrons after absorbing one neutron.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Ronen fissile rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fissile_material), all heavy isotopes with :
$$ \lgroup ~
90 \le Z \le 100, ~\text{and}
\\
~~~2Z - N \in [41,42,43,44,45]
   ~\rgroup
 $$

should be fissile and hence have valid concept of critical mass. (Here $Z, N$ are proton and neutron numbers respectively).